# Typescript 2.x control flow not picking up type

Tags: typescript

I have a function where `input` is either a Dictionary or an array of Dictionaries:

```
public convert(input: IDictionary<any> | IDictionary<any>[], additionalProps?: string[]) {
  if ( input instanceof Array ) {
    this._handlers.forEach(fn => {
      input = input.map(i => fn(i));
    });
    return input.map(i => this._convert(i, additionalProps));
  } else {
    this._handlers.forEach(fn => {
      input = fn(input);
    });
    return this._convert(input, additionalProps);
  }
}
```

The function does what I need it to but Typescript is not correctly identifying that the `input` reference within the **if** block is always going to be an array so it gives me the following error:

> Property 'map' does not exist on type 'IDictionary'

I would have thought with Typescript 2.x it would have used the if block as part of its *control flow analysis* to determine that the union type could only now be the `IDictionary<any>[]` type. Is my understanding wrong? Is there a correct way to notate this?

---

p.s. I'm using Typescript 2.1.4

---

some additional context on **handlers**:

```
export default class Mapper {
  private _handlers: Function[] = [];
```

and handlers are set with the following public interface:

```
public handlers(fn: Function | Function[]) {
  if(fn instanceof Array) {
    this._handlers.concat(fn);
  } else {
    this._handlers.push(fn);
  }

  return this;
}
```

---

the entire class can be found in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/ksnyde/c9ed19e8c318d107f88f655ebf749dfb). An example usage of the mapper class would be ...

```
const mapping: IMapping = {
  id: 'invoiceId',
  type: (context) => context['type'] === 'ACCREC' ? 'accounts-receivable' : 'accounts-payable',
  date: (context) => xero.xeroDate(context['date']),
  dueDate: (context) => xero.xeroDate(context['dueDate']),
  lastUpdated: (context) => xero.xeroDate(context['updatedDateUtc']),
  payments: (context) => context['payments'].map((p: IDictionary<any>) => p['PaymentID']),
  prePayments: (context) => context['prepayments'].map((p: IDictionary<any>) => p['PaymentID']),
  overPayments: (context) => context['overpayments'].map((p: IDictionary<any>) => p['PaymentID'])
};

const mapper = new Mapper(mapping);
return mapper
  .handler(utils.camelCaseProperties)  
  .convert(invoices);
```

---

Finally, `IDictionary` is defined as:

```
interface IDictionary<T> {
  [key: string]: T;
};
```

Comment: What's `this._handlers`?

Comment: it's a _private_ instance variable which holds an array of handler functions.

Comment: Yeah, that I understood, but what do these functions return?

Comment: I've added some more context to the question ... does that answer your question?

Comment: in terms of what these handler functions return ... it's a dictionary or an array of dictionaries.

Comment: What's `IDictionary`?

Comment: added `IDictionary` to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [type assertion](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html):

```
if ( input instanceof Array ) {
    let inputArray = <IDictionary<any>[]> input;
    this._handlers.forEach(fn => {
      inputArray = inputArray.map(i => fn(i));
    });
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Does this necessitate the introduction of a new variable or can I assert on the `input` variable directly? ... guess it does. That explains why my earlier attempt at this failed.

Comment: I guess you could also do this: `inputArray = <IDictionary<any>[]> inputArray.map(i => fn(i));`  but you will have to assert it every time you use the variable.

Comment: There's no need for type assertion, it's enough to do `let inputArray = input`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are changing the type of `input` in two different places:

```
input = input.map(i => fn(i));
```

And

```
input = fn(input);
```

You can do this:

```
public convert(input: IDictionary<any> | IDictionary<any>[], additionalProps?: string[]) {
    let input2;

    if ( input instanceof Array ) {
        this._handlers.forEach(fn => {
            input2 = input.map(i => fn(i));
        });

        return input2.map(i => this._convert(i, additionalProps));
    } else {
        this._handlers.forEach(fn => {
            input2 = fn(input);
        });

        return this._convert(input2, additionalProps);
    }
}
```

Or change the type of `_handler` to be:

```
private _handlers = [] as Array<() => IDictionary<any>[]>;
```

Comment: i like the definition of `_handlers` approach but can't get it to work. The functions always just transform a single dictionary to another dictionary (I think i misstated that earlier) so I think your above solution should be: `private _handlers = [] as Array<() => IDictionary<any>>;` (aka, I removed the array of dictionaries in favor of a singular dictionary.

Comment: I get the error `Type 'Function' provides no match for the signature '(): IDictionary<any>' `

Comment: in the singular handler block I get this error: `(parameter) input: IDictionary<any> | IDictionary<any>[]`

Comment: These functions, what do they do? You can probably have a better type for that as well..

Comment: they convert an 3rd party input dictionary to a normalized dictionary; so a common handler function would be to camelize the property names in the dictionary. Another one be to convert dates to unix epoc format, etc.

Comment: Can you maybe share the entire class and other relevant information? Or maybe you can come up with a simple example that illustrates the problem?

Comment: here's the entire class: https://gist.github.com/ksnyde/c9ed19e8c318d107f88f655ebf749dfb

Comment: I'll add a usage scenario to the question.